# CSS tabs expand height to content

Tags: html, css, height, expand

The current problem I am facing is I'm looking to place a tabbed content box on an eBay listing. Currently a jQuery solution will not work as eBay strips it from the code

I have turned to a pure css approach but have run into problems changing the height of the tabs to resize based on the content.(which is generated and inserted by eBay)

here is my css

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 100px;
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

in action [jsfiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/nYcR3/)

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this then you first need to change these two CSS rules to what is below:

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  display:block;
}
```

This was set as a z-index but needs to be changed to display:block; because of the next step:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  display:none;
  min-width:700px;
}
```

Remove `bottom:0;` and `right:0;` and add in `display:none;` and `min-width:700px;`. 
That is all that is needed! It will automatically change height depending on how large the text inside is.
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/nYcR3/1/)
Hope This Helps!

Comment: what about if I need to do the opposite thing? I mean setting the height of tabs content automatically choosing the highest one among the tabs. I'm actually using a jQuery script to the same stuff as above, not just CSS. Naturally I do not want to put min-height value because those tabs are part of a webview showed in and Android app, so the screen size is always different

Comment: @brainvision you should write a separate question about your issue. Feel free to post it here after, and i'll take a look :)

Comment: @JacobGray here is my requirement and this green area need to expanded with tabs content, please help me, here is my working demo  
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/nYcR3/36/)